# display string data in listview as string value changes every yime

Tags: java, android, string, listview, arraylist

I have a service and one activity in my application. service acquires a string by the user's action and that string is passed to the activity. Here i am getting the string value to the activity successfully and displaying on the activity screen.

I have a listview in activity and the string values should display in that list orderly. My problem is that i am able to display only one item in the listview which is recently entered. The previous entered strings are not displaying.

So every time i have to get string from service and that string should display in listview along with previous list items.
Please help me.. thank you.

My Activity is...

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String pichi;
SharedPreferences pref=null;
ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> strArray;
int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.offlineList);

    pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    pichi=pref.getString("KEY","default");

    strArray=new ArrayList<String>();
    if (strArray.contains(pichi)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Link already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        int count = list.getCount();
        for ( i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            strArray.add("Row" + i);
        }
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);
        if (!list.equals(i)) {
            strArray.add(pichi);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

public void startService(View view) {
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckService.class));

}
```

}

where startService(View view) is an action of button pressed.

My Service is....

```
   public class CheckService extends Service {


public CheckService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

String a;
Intent dialogIntent;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received Start id" + startId + ":" + intent);

    final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            a = clipboard.getText().toString();
            if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(a).matches()){

                dialogIntent = new Intent(CheckService.this, DialogActivity.class);
                dialogIntent.putExtra("text",a);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
            else if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(a)){
             //   Toast.makeText(CheckService.this, "text is not a url link", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // Perform your long running operations here.
 //   Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopService(dialogIntent);
}
```

}

In the service i have an alert dialog from where i can get the string value...

My Dialog Activity is.....

```
  public class DialogActivity extends Activity{

AlertDialog alert;
String receivedText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    receivedText=bundle.getString("text","default");

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder
            .setTitle("yoLobee")
            .setMessage("save to yoLobee offline..?" )
            .setIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNeutralButton("SHARE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, receivedText);
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,receivedText));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    alert.dismiss();
                    alert.dismiss();
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(DialogActivity.this, "Link saved to yoLobee..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                    edit.putString("KEY",receivedText);
                    edit.commit();
               //     edit.apply();

                }
            });

    alert = builder.create();
    alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
    alert.setCancelable(true);
    alert.show();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(alert.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    Window window = alert.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
    window.setAttributes(wlp);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        alert.cancel();
        alert.dismiss();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    alert.cancel();
    alert.dismiss();
}
```

}

So from the dialog activity i am getting the string value and displaying in the list.
The list is displaying only the recent string value from service as it gets one value at a time. I want the list to display list of strings which are retreived form the service.

Comment: please post your adapter code...

Comment: I dont have any adapter code... i am using array adapter as adapter to display items in listview. As i guess adapter is to display array data in list, i need the array data to be working fine.

Comment: i dont have much knowledge on this, if there is any changes that i have to  be made plz suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line `int count = list.getCount();` in `onCreate` returns 0 beacuse you didnt add any item to `list` so far.

Comment: yes, i didnt add items to list, that is my problem. every time if i pass the string to strArray, it will display only that item. so atmost list will contain only one item. how to make array list of strings.... from my passed value.

Comment: Check http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android out. If you wanna use service and update list so you should use receiver too.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you provide piece of code to look at it.
Reading your problem it seems that you are over writing the array you are using for populating list.

Just get the string from activity and add it in array which you are using to display listview and call notifyDataSetChanged(). It will work

Comment: i tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() also. It didnt work. how to add the string in array to display listview and that array should contain all the values as i enter new string each time.